# Issue with closing dialog box when clicking on NavLink in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, react-router-dom

I'm currently working on a React application and have implemented a dialog box using the `Dialog` component from the Material-UI library. The dialog box contains a navigation menu, and I want it to close when the user clicks on one of the navigation links (`NavLink`) in desktop mode.

Here's the relevant code snippet:

Dialog component code

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

// Dialog opening and closing functions

const handleOpen = () => {
  setOpen(true);
};

const handleClose = () => {
  setOpen(false);
};

// JSX code for the dialog box

<Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
  <div className="dialog-content">
    {/* Navigation links */}
    {navItems.map((item) => (
      <NavLink
        key={item.id}
        to={item.href}
        className="-m-2 block p-2 text-gray-500"
        onClick={handleClose} // Issue here: dialog doesn't close
      >
        {item.name}
      </NavLink>
    ))}
  </div>
</Dialog>
```

The problem I'm facing is that the dialog box doesn't close when I click on a `NavLink`. The `onClick` handler is correctly invoked, but the dialog remains open. I suspect there might be an issue with how I'm implementing the `onClick` handler.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to properly close the dialog box when clicking on a `NavLink` in React.

Comment: what is react-router-dom version you are using?

Comment: @CodeThing ^6.10.0

Comment: Seems working fine for me: [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-t3szrm?file=demo.js)

Comment: @CodeThing I have a navigation bar with 5 NavLinks on click of those links the dialog is not closing I tried the above code also which you mentioned in the stackblitz. I am calling  onClick={handleClose} on NavLinks but it's not closing the Dialog.

Comment: Yeah, but that's what it is in stackblitz as well. It is working fine there right? It doesn't matter you have 5 links or 1. So that is pointing out that the issue must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to reproduce the exact issue you describe with the code you've provided, but I suspect you are rendering the `Dialog` component within another interactive element/component that is triggering the `handleOpen` handler or otherwise updating the `open` state to open the dialog.

The issue here is that the `NavLink` click event bubbles up, e.g. propagates, to the element that opens the dialog. The `NavLink`'s `onClick` handler calls `handleClose` and the state is updated but at the same time the event propagated up to the root element and `handleOpen` is called and this enqueued state update cancels the closure.

The fix is to call `stopPropagation` on the `onClick` event object.

```
const handleOpen = () => {
  setOpen(true);
};

const handleClose = (e) => {
  e.stopPropagation(); // <-- prevent further bubbling of click event

  setOpen(false);
};

...

<Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
  <div className="dialog-content">
    {/* Navigation links */}
    {navItems.map((item) => (
      <NavLink
        key={item.id}
        to={item.href}
        className="-m-2 block p-2 text-gray-500"
        onClick={handleClose}
      >
        {item.name}
      </NavLink>
    ))}
  </div>
</Dialog>
```

[image: Edit issue-with-closing-dialog-box-when-clicking-on-navlink-in-react]